# Using PHP inside of HTML to redirect to a random site

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to be able to have the user click a button, and be redirected to a random page.

I tried putting the PHP inside of JavaScript, and that inside of HTML, like this:

```
<script>
<button onclick="var jsVar = "<?php 
$urls = array("www.site1.com", "www.site2.com", "www.site3.com","www.site4.com"); 
$url = $urls[array_rand($urls)]; 
header("Location: http://$url"); ?>"">Click</button>
</script>
```

I know this may have many errors, and help is very appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: do a form with a button then when the button is clicked go to random page

Comment: You can do this in Javascript, you don't need php at all

Answer (score 1):

PHP script will generate random URL, when you click on the button, it will call `randsite($url)` JavaScript function, that function will redirect you to random sites.

```
<?php
    $urls = array("http://www.site1.com", "http://www.site2.com", "http://www.site3.com","http://www.site4.com"); 
    // select random url
    $rand = $urls[mt_rand(0, count($urls) - 1)];
?>

<button onclick="randsite(<?php echo "'".$rand."'"; ?>)">Click</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function randsite($url){
    window.location = $url;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<?php
$urls = array("www.site1.com", "www.site2.com", "www.site3.com","www.site4.com"); 
$url = $urls[array_rand($urls)]; 
?>
<button onclick="myfunction();">Click</button>
<script>
function myfunction(){
    var href = "<?php echo $url?>";
    window.location.href = "http://"+href;
}
</script>
```

Comment: It didn't work, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**PHP + HTML + JS :**

```
 <?php $url = "http://....."; ?>
    <button name="redirect"onclick="redirectFunc(<?php echo $url; ?>);">Redirect with button</button>

    <script>
    function redirectFunc($url){
        window.location.href = "<?php echo $url?>";
    }
    </script>
```

**Redirect HTML + PHP:**
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Suppose your php file is located at the address:
http://www.yourserver.com/form-action.php 
In this case, PHP_SELF will contain: "/form-action.php"

```
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
     // type means what should button do submit -> submit your post
     // name how you will recognize which post was sended
     // value value of button which you can get
     <button type="submit" name="redirect" value="redirectValue" id="redirect">Redirect with button post</button>
</form>
```

and then you handle your post on button click

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['redirect'])) { 
   // rand your url
   // echo $_POST['redirect']; will output redirectValue
    header('Location: http://....');
}
?>
```

**Or with ahref:**
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

```
//or you can use ahref e.g
    <?php $url = "http://..."; 
    // code for randoming url
    ?>

      <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">Redirect with a href</a></p>
```

**HTML + JS:**

```
<button id="buttonID">redirect</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // here you can rand your urls and choose one of them to redirect
    document.getElementById("buttonID").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "http://...";
    };
</script>
```